# Weekly Facebook Scores clearing?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

we want to do something that's relatively common among mobile games. We want to reset our Facebook scoreboard every week. I am surprised to find that - looking around - there is no automatic way to do this.

Is it in the plans to offer this functionality? A probably easier thing on Facebook's end that would work for us is if when we ask for friends scores, we get the date of each score, so we can then filter out the scores that are too old.

Other than that, it seems that we'd have to write a Windows Service or Cron task to call the Facebook every week and do this (or do it manually from Putty or other tool), neither of which seem accceptable for this small task.

Thank you and let us know!
-Brian Hunsaker
Technical Director @ DarkTonic Games

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell Facebook to wipe your app's Scores automatically, but you only need to make a single API call to wipe all scores:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[APP ID]?access_token=[APP ACCESS TOKEN]&method=delete`

This is mentioned here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/

Comment: I know we only need to make a single call. But doing that simple thing entails writing a service so it can be done in an automated way with no maintenance. As stated above, it would be better if we either could know the date of each score, or if Facebook Developer could have a place for us to specify a schedule to reset scores. A whole lot of people would want and use this. I bet this is not the first time this has been asked for.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only way, you'd have to write a cron job to regularly purge the scores with the app access token - which if you're not verifying it works is a one-liner, and isn't much more complicated if you also check a random set of users to verify the scores were reset

Answer (score 0):

The call to delete all the scores from your facebook App is as follows (may have changed):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[APP ID]/scores?access_token=[APP TOKEN]&method=delete
```

it should return true.